# Python "with" statement: __exit__() ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Considering this small Python class, whenever I stop the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the `__exit__` function is run before the exception is raised:

```
import time


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('------ cleanup ------')


with MyClass():
    time.sleep(100)
```

Running:

```
$ python3 test.py 
^C------ cleanup ------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    time.sleep(100)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

In a similar piece of code that subclasses the Chrome WebDriver, why is my cleanup function ignored?

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class WebDriver(selenium.webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.url = url

    def __enter__(self):
        self.get(self.url)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('------ cleanup ------')


with WebDriver('https://google.com') as driver:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'lst-ib').send_keys('Search')
```

Running:

```
$ python3 test2.py 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 19, in <module>
    with WebDriver('https://google.com') as driver:
  File "test2.py", line 9, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/vagrant/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 90, in start
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Forcing it with a `try: ... finally:` statement works, though:

```
try:
    with WebDriver('https://google.com') as driver:
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'lst-ib').send_keys('Search')
finally:
    print('------ cleanup ------')
```

Running:

```
^C------ cleanup ------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 20, in <module>
    with WebDriver('https://google.com') as driver:
  File "test2.py", line 9, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/vagrant/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/vagrant/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 90, in start
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: You should return the value you want assigned to `driver` from your `__enter__` method.

Comment: @PaulRooney Ah, yes, I forgot that in example, but that is not the real problem! The real code already has that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the traceback shows that you were still in the __init__() of your WebDriver object - in other words, the **with** statement had not yet executed, Python was still evaluating its parameter.  I'm not sure of the exact rules, but I'm pretty sure that __exit__() will never be called if __enter__() hadn't been called yet.

Comment: Or if `__enter__` did not finish:an interrupt during the `get` would not startthe `with` block as well